# Hunter and Rabbit Bayesian Probability

Tags: probability, game-theory, bayesian

I've been asked to do this by process of game theory and probability (namely Bayesian theory).

**Here is the problem:**
There is a Hunter (H) and a Rabbit (R). They are playing the following game:
- There are 20 holes on a line numbered from 1 to 20.

The game begins:
- in the first period (t=0) H chooses a hole and R chooses a hole 
- if H and R choose the same hole, H wins (because he captures the Rabbit) and the game finishes. Otherwise, the game continues

If the game does not finish a t, we enter the next period: t+1

- in t+1:
- R MUST move away from the hole he was in period t and can move only to the holes that are adjacent to the hole he was in at t.   i.e: if he was in hole  n ( for example 15), he must move either in hole n-1 (i.e., 14) or in hole n+1 (i.e. 16). while if he was on hole 1 (20), he must move in hole 2 (19).
- H can choose a hole with no restrictions (i.e. he can choose any hole in the list 1,2,3...20)
- if H and R choose the same hole, H wins (because he captures the Rabbit) and the game finishes. Otherwise, the game continues

.....
if  R does not lose in 100 rounds, he wins the game.

**Questions:**

- Can you tell me if H has a strategy to win the game for SURE? If so, describe this strategy.

**Consider the following modification of the game:**

- In each period,  H announces to R the hole he is going to choose before R decides where to move.
- Can you tell me if H has a strategy to win the game? 
  If so, describe this strategy.

Thanks!

Comment: 1) What have you tried ? 2) Do the holes moved to remain unknown to each other ? 3) "R wins (because he captures the Rabbit)" I presume you mean $H$ wins ?

Comment: 1) I hoped for someone to give me a starting backbone as I'm really confused as how to start this question. I was thinking of using permutations but I'm unsure of how I would plan it out. 2) Can you elaborate? 3) Yes that was a typo! Thanks I'll fix that!

Comment: Does $H$ know where $R$ is at the time $t$ before choosing a hole for $t+1$?

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{Hint: }$ If $R$ is at $1$ or $20$ at time $t$, can $H$ win at time $t+1$?